# "there are tablets for each" or "there is a tablet for each"

Tags: descriptive-grammar

Which is correct? I want to say there is ONE tablet for each emperor and avoid any ambiguity whatsoever. Which one is best？

**Inside the hall there are tablets for each of the former Qing dynasty emperors.** 
or
**Inside the hall there are tablets: one for each of the former Qing dynasty emperors.**
or
**Inside the hall there is a tablet for each of the former Qing dynasty emperors.**

Comment: I would say the **third one** because it's simple, grammatical and conveys your intended message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second and third specify *one* tablet per emperor, where the first could mean several tablets for each.

Comment: Right.  And the second one implies that there was more than one Qing dynasty emperor, while the third one says nothing about that.