# Should I use a singular form or a plural form before a clause starting with "for each"?

Tags: grammatical-number

In this sentence, should I use the singular "due date" or the plural "due dates"?

**Please let us know your earliest possible due dates for each product.**

Each product should have only one due date. But as a whole, there should be several due dates as we have more than one product.

Comment: Please read the FAQ here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: The current formulation allows more than one "earliest possible due date" for some product.  (Does not require more than one, just allows it.)  I could imagine an answer with more than one ... "The earliest possible due date is July 1, but if that falls on a weekend, the due date is the following Monday."

Comment: Using "Please let us know your earliest possible due date(s) for each product", may cover both singular and plural.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better match on ELL.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["there are tablets for each" or "there is a tablet for each"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286779/there-are-tablets-for-each-or-there-is-a-tablet-for-each)

Answer (score 1):

> Please  let us  know your earliest possible  due dates  for each  product.

Since you say each product it should be  possible due date even though multiple due dates for multiple products.

Each product has only one due date. Due dates mean each product has different due dates.

Comment: You sure meant to edit the sentence to *date* but forgot it.

Answer (score -1):

If there is *only one* earliest possible due date for each product (as would seem to be the intention):

> Please let us know your earliest possible due **date** for each
> product.

If there are *alternative* early possible due dates for each product (unlikely, but perhaps one might say “Our earliest possible due dates are the 5th of January, or if you are away then, the 6th January.”):

> Please let us know your earliest possible due **dates** for each
> product.

(Not sure what a “due date” is, except for a pregnancy. Did the OP mean “delivery date”?)